# Display Product Options with the selected Configuration Picklist attribute value

Tags: filters, cpq

New to Salesforce CPQ.
Below is a scenario I am trying to implement.

There is a Product Bundle "PB" which has 2 Product Options PB1 and PB2. A Configuration attribute of Type Picklist is created at PB which is named as "Labor Type". It has 2 values - Mechanical ad Technical.
When we click on "Add Products" , the Configuration Page of PB will be displayed with "Labor Type" visible.

Query - If "Mechanical" is selected in "Labor Type" , then Product Option "PB1" should be shown . If "Technical" is selected in "Labor Type" , then Product Option "PB2" should be shown.
How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer, you need a Product rule of the type selection. Coming to the scenario do the following

Step 1 : Create a Product Rule of type Selection where the Action will be to show and enable/add PB1 for the CONDITION "Config Attribute =Mechanical"

Step 2: With in the same product rule now do Hide/Remove PB2 for the CONDITION "Config Attribute =Mechanical"

This will solve for what happens when the Config attribute = Mechanical. Similarly create a second price rule for the other picklist value

Step 3 : Create a Product Rule of type Selection where the Action will be to show and enable/add PB2 for the CONDITION "Config Attribute =Technical"

Step 4: With in the same product rule now do Hide/Remove PB1 for the CONDITION "Config Attribute =Technical"

P.S: The link in the comments above didn't work for me so I was hoping this would clear your query. Use the same logic for similar requirements

Note: Make sure to check the checkbox that copies the config attribute value to the product options else when ever you try to reconfigure the bundle the values get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a product rule for it. Kindly refer this link to move ahead:- [CPQ Configuration](https://www.forcetalks.com/videos/configuration-attribute-in-salesforce-cpq-salesforce-development-tutorial-learn-salesforce-series-by-algoworks/)